# skimage module missing while using auto-py-to-exe app

Tags: numpy, scikit-image, auto-py-to-exe

I wrote a program in Python and when running it under PyCharm it's working properly. I decided to use AUTO-PY-TO-EXE app to be able to share the program with a friend. The compile process was successful but when running the executable file, I'm getting this error:

```
No module named 'skimage.data._fetchers'
```

All the dependencies are downloaded into my computer since it's working under PyCharm.

I had this issue before and re-install `skimage` with dependencies including `numpy`. However, it didn't fix the problem and even created more issues... all my python programs were not running at all due to `numpy` version. After re-installing `numpy 1.23.1`, all my programs were working properly again but with no option of making it executable.

I'm reluctant to re-install `skimage` with dependencies since it was a nightmare to get my programs to work properly again. Has someone had the same issue? Is there a way to rectify the problem without re-installing `skimage` and dependencies again? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Similar issue on the pyinstaller issue tracker: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4984 (The auto-py-to-exe application uses pyinstaller internally.)